# Getting String from one from to another c#

Tags: c#, forms, get

I have been looking at this for a while and I can't seem to get it. I have to get a string from one form to another but it doesn't work, I tried using get but it just threw that "get" didn't exist in this context. Here is my code.
This is on the main form:

```
  public string SavePoint()
  {     
        string settings = "";
        string archive = "";
        if (rb_Backup.Checked)
        {
            settings = "backup";
        }
        else if (rb_Restore.Checked)
        {
            settings = "restore";
        }
        else if (rb_Sync.Checked)
        {
            settings = "sync";
        }
        if (cb_Archive.Checked)
        {
            archive = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            archive = "false";
        }

        string savePoint = txt_From.Text + "\r\n" + txt_To.Text + "\r\n" + settings + "\r\n" + archive;
        return savePoint;
  }
```

And this is on the form that is trying to access the data:

```
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm_Main mainForm = new frm_Main();
        string saveData = mainForm.SavePoint();
        string savePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Profiles";
        if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
        }
        StreamWriter saveFile = new StreamWriter(savePath + "\\" + txt_Save.Text + ".txt");
        saveFile.WriteLine(saveData);
        saveFile.Close();
        this.Close();
    }
```

I am learning which is one of the reasons I'm making this software.

Kindest regards,

Scobbo

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete error / stacktrace?

Comment: Can the main form pass the string to the child form when the child form is first created, or is the parent form being modified after the child form is created and before the save button is clicked (thus forcing you to pass the data right when the button is pressed)?

Comment: i`ve tried the code and it works properly as is....

Comment: @Servy no, basically it just opens the form and when you click the save button it takes the data and writes it to a file. The user shouldn't be modifying it when the save dialog is open. I will restrict that later but at the moment I think you can modify that but that won't be happening. Also the error I get is :
Error 3 The name 'get' does not exist in the current context D:\Projects\Software\Quick Backup Utility\Quick Backup Utility\Form1.cs 204 13 Quick Backup Utility

Comment: @Abdulrahman_88 It compiles and runs without error, but as he's not accessing the proper instance of the form, it doesn't contain the user inputted data.

Comment: @user2106265 Then you just need to pass the string when the child form is first created.

Comment: @Servy so as a parameter? I will research this. Thankyou

Comment: @user2106265 see my answer below. It should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than waiting until the `btn_Save_Click` method to try to get the information from the parent form; have the parent form pass the information when the child form is first created.

Just create a simple property like this on the child form:

```
public string SavePath {get;set;}
```

Then have the main form set it when it first creates it:

```
SaveDialog child = new SaveDialog();
child.SavePath = SavePoint();
child.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: And I should do this for all the data, there is a set of data to write that comes from the main form and the save path is just set to a single folder with the user able to type in a file name.

Comment: Oh get goes outside a method and in the class. I get it now. Thank you so much! You are my hero. It all works and best of all I now understand how to use "get". You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the owner on the second form before showing it from your main form. Then you can access the main form from the second form.

Example would be - Main form button that will open up the second form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Owner = this;
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Then we have the second form - we want to pull out the data from the Main Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get our owner form i.e: Form1.cs

            Form1 frm = (Form1)this.Owner;  // Here we cast the owner form as Form1
            MessageBox.Show(frm.teststr()); // You can access the functions/procedure from the main form here
        }
```

You don't want to keep creating new instances of the Main Form because a new instance means that all data/processing done on the current Main Form is set to default. So you want to pass the current Main Form object over to the Second Form. That's what we did here.

Comment: This really isn't a good practice, as you're coupling the child form very tightly with the parent form.  You can just have the parent form provide the string to the child form when the child is first created, which means that the child doesn't need to know anything about the parent.

Comment: The fact that he's new makes it all the more important to learn how to do things *properly* from the start rather than picking up bad habits early on that he'll need to unlearn in the future.

Comment: I meant I am still new, and your solution should be used. :) I was just trying to help. No harm.

Answer (score -2):

To get the point you should use a property not a method. This should look like

```
public string SavePoint
{
   get
   {
       string settings = "";
       string archive = "";
       if (rb_Backup.Checked)
       {
           settings = "backup";
       }
       else if (rb_Restore.Checked)
       {
           settings = "restore";
       }
       else if (rb_Sync.Checked)
       {
           settings = "sync";
       }
       if (cb_Archive.Checked)
       {
           archive = "true";
       }
       else
       {
           archive = "false";
       }

       string savePoint = txt_From.Text + "\r\n" + txt_To.Text + "\r\n" + settings + "\r\n" + archive;
       return savePoint;
   }
}
```

Comment: and change `string saveData = mainForm.SavePoint();` to `string saveData = mainForm.SavePoint;`

Comment: A property basically is a method with slightly different syntax.  This answer also doesn't address the fact that the problem the OP has is accessing the proper instance of the parent form.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried and it told me that get doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @user2106265, you are creating a new MainForm instead of referencing current one. Try creating a method/property in new form where you can pass reference to Mainform. In vb.net, it a little easier to get the reference without additional work.